# In R, with regular expressions, how do I distinguish between "Normalized_Signal" and "Signal"?

Tags: regex, r

I'm trying to figure out how to overcome greedy pattern matching in R. I have a dataframe, and I'm trying to go through each column and pick out the ones that say "Signal" (e.g., Signal.1, Signal.2, Signal.3), but not the ones that say "Normalized_Signal" (e.g., Normalized_Signal.1, Normalized_Signal.2).

How can I distinguish between these two strings using regular expressions?

Here's what I'm doing now:

```
 # create a toy dataframe - I only want the ones that say "Signal.1, Signal.2"
 df <- data.frame( Signal.1 = c(1,1), Normalized_Signal.1 = c(1,1), SDEV.1 = c(1,1), Signal.2 = c(1,1),  Normalized_Signal.2 = c(1,1), SDEV.2 = c(1,1) )

 # attempt 1: pull out all the rows that say "signal" 
 df[, grep("Signal", colnames(df))]

 # attempt 2: grepl
 df[, grepl("Signal*", colnames(df))]

 # attempt 3: add word boundary
 df[, grep("\bSignal", colnames(df))]
```

I feel like I'm honing in but I can't figure out exactly what syntax to use - any ideas?

Comment: If those two are the only options (normalized/not), you could also `grep` for `normalized`.... Or use grep("^Signal"), it finds signal at the start of the string.

Comment: Good point! Unfortunately, there are other columns - e.g. SDEV, FLAGS, S_N. So df, !(grepl("Normalized", colnames(df)))] Produces all columns except for the ones that say Normalized. Will edit original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the whole string you are matching against should begin with `Signal`, you should anchor your regex:

`^Signal`

---

Your first attempt will find `Signal` anywhere in the string.

Your second attempt matches `Signa` because `*` means 0 or more.

Your third attempt forgets to escape the escape.

Comment: Thank you - this solved my problem, and the extra details are extremely helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Your last attempt works if you remember to protect the backslash properly (i.e. *two* backslashes):

```
df[, grep("\\bSignal", colnames(df))]
```